# two consecutive middle-anchored lines in svg?

Tags: svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg height="140" width="700" style="font-size:100px;font-family:serif"> 
<text x="350" y="75" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
     style="line-height:115%;text-anchor:middle;">BIG LINE</text>

  <text x="350" y="120" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
       style="text-anchor:middle;font-size:20%">This is a very long line with a lot of text</text>
</svg>
```

does not center the second line in my viewer.  (I doubled up on middle to make it better!)  how does one do this?

Here is a related but not identical question: can I put multiple lines into one text?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg height="140" width="700" style="font-size:100px;font-family:serif"> 
<text x="350" y="75" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
     style="line-height:115%;text-anchor:middle;">BIG LINE<br/>no</text>
</svg>
```

but svg cannot break lines.

My ultimate intent is to have one centered headline followed by a smaller-font but longer centered headline, that is scalable inside my html browser to stretch the width of the page.  svg seems to be the best way to do this...maybe.  NOTE: The line break is an aside.  The real issue is the centering.

Comment: I think if you remove the BR it should work.

Comment: nope, it does not on my imageviewer on linux.  it should...

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is not a valid SVG element.  You can't randomly insert HTML tags in an SVG document.

If you really need to include HTML, you can use the `<foreignObject>` element.

```
<svg height="300" width="700" style="font-size:100px;font-family:serif"> 

    <foreignObject x="100" width="500" height="550">
      <!-- XHTML content goes here -->
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        style="font-size:100px; line-height:115%; color:blue; text-align: center;">
          <p>BIG LINE<br/>no</p>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>

    <text x="350" y="120" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
       style="text-anchor:middle;font-size:20%">This is a very long line with a lot of text</text>
</svg>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ja6M2/1/)

Comment: this doesn't display anything on the first line for me on linux' imageviewer.  the line break was more of an aside.  my real problem is the centering.

Comment: but thank you for telling me how to fix the PS: part, with the html and break in it

Comment: It is probably because the SVG renderer you are using doesn't support `<foreignObject>`.